# Does the gravitation force depend on temperature?

Tags: gravity, experimental-physics, temperature

C. Y. Lo says:

"*According to Newton and Einstein, gravitation is independent of the temperature, but **experiments show that the gravitation of a metal is reduced as temperature increases***. ~~~. "
http://meetings.aps.org/Meeting/APR19/Session/H11.9

What is the experiment mentioned by the author?
If anyone knows that except the paper written by AL Dmitriev, please provide relevant information.

Comment: A Google search on Gravitation Metal Temperature turned up some relevant links. I have no idea what results were presented when the paper was presented.

Comment: @Peter Thank you for your comment. Probably, the first result found by Google search is the paper written by AL Dmitriev. I read the paper already, but as far as I know is, the paper has not cited by other authors. So, I don't think the Dmitriev's paper is not that mentioned by C. Y. Lo.

Comment: If someone has a valid experiment that disproves both Newton and Einstein, I would expect Physicists to be running about, mad with excitement. Since they're not, I assume that this experiment is not valid (or made-up - it happens). Seriously - new physics of this type is a dream.

Comment: @simonatrcl I totally agree with you. Nonetheless, I believe that sometimes opportunities knock on doors weakly. I think that Dmitriev's results are not sufficiently disproved by experiments and further experiments are needed. Nullius in verba...